# Phone number regex validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Need to validate phone numbers which are separated by comma and it can have country code as start parameter.
I need to do temporary validation in front end side such as validating different numbers

1. number with country code(min length and max length should be specified): +919845098450
2. number without country code(min length and max length should be specified):9845098450

and these numbers are separated by comma(+919845098450,9845098450 etc)
so for i have done it for single phone number .

```
^([+])?[0-9()\-#+]*$
```

and comma separated

```
^([+])?[,\d{9}]*$
```

but the above regex is not **showing error when** the input ends with comma (+919845098450,9845098450,).

I need to do it for comma separated numbers in jquery/javascript.

if possible i need to specify min and max length with and without country code.
your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this,

```
/^(?:\+\d{2})?\d{10}(?:,(?:\+\d{2})?\d{10})*$/.test(str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eA4zT0/1)

- `(?:\+\d{2})?` helps to match an optional country code.
- `\d{10}` matches the 10 digit number.
- `(?:,(?:\+\d{2})?\d{10})*` helps to match the following zero or more phone numbers.

Comment: it is showing no match for "+919845098450,9845098450,+91897654234". can you check once?

Comment: because there is only 9 digits in the last (excluding country code)

Comment: if you don't care about the following digits then replace `\d{10}` in the above with `\d+`

Comment: Thanks It works well.How can we achive same if (+) doesn't exist and only country code is appended.?
 Ex : 919845098450

Comment: just add `?` next to `\+`