# Phone number regex validation [Areacode and phone number]

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

My requirement is a bit different from the normal international phone number validations.

I want a regex which:

1. Need to limit the phone number to 10.
2. If a "-" is entered, then a 4 max character limit should be set before the "-", and after that 10 character limit.

Example : 1234567890,123456789, 0000-1234567890, 000-123456789 (area code- phonennumber)

Can someone point me to a regex which validates this?
I did look through a lot of [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285456/phone-number-regex-validation), [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?rq=1).

Thanks

Comment: `^(\d{1,4}-)?\d{1,10}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{1,4}-)?\d{1,10}$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/3

You have not defined a lower limit.So this will match `0-0` too.You can replace `1` with whatever lower limit you want.

Comment: lol.. i literally was just about to post this *exact* same regex.  beat me to it